# Unable to get aws credentials from IAM role

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using SDK version 2.8.21 to use KMS.

I have a config.php file that contains

```
<?php

// File saved as /path/to/custom/config.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache;
use Guzzle\Cache\DoctrineCacheAdapter;

// Create a cache adapter that stores data on the filesystem
$cacheAdapter = new DoctrineCacheAdapter(new FilesystemCache('/tmp/cache'));

return array(
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'credentials.cache' => $cacheAdapter
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The following is test.php file that I am using to do a test encryption.

```
<?php

  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use Aws\Common\Aws;

  // Create the AWS service builder, providing the path to the config file
  try {

    $keyId = '<KMSKEYALIAS>';

    $aws = Aws::factory('config.php');
    $client = $aws->get('kms');

    $result = $client->encrypt(array(
      'KeyId' => $keyId,
      'Plaintext' => 'This is the song that never ends...'
    ));

    print_r($result);

  }
  catch (\Exception $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n\n";
  }
```

When I execute php test.php I get "A region is required when using AWS Key Management Service".

Thinking it may be a server IAM issue we used the CLI tools to test.

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id <KMSKEYALIAS> --plaintext "1\!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+" --query CiphertextBlob --output text | base64 --decode > /tmp/encrypt.txt
```

And /tmp/encrypted.txt contained the encrypted data.

I am at a loss and could really use some help in either figuring out if this is a bug in aws or if I am doing something wrong.

I am currently unable to upgrade to v3.x because we are using php 5.4 and upgrading to 5.5 isn't something we can do right now.

Comment: you need to specify a `region` in your `config.php` file. here is a list of valid regions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#kms_region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cmorrissey mentioned I needed to set the region.  The documentation and blog posts I read did not make this clear imo.  This answer is in case anyone else doesn't find the documentation abundantly clear.

```
<?php

// File saved as /path/to/custom/config.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache;
use Guzzle\Cache\DoctrineCacheAdapter;

// Create a cache adapter that stores data on the filesystem
$cacheAdapter = new DoctrineCacheAdapter(new FilesystemCache('/tmp/cache'));

return array(
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'region' => 'us-east-1',
                'credentials.cache' => $cacheAdapter
            )
        )
    )
);
```